# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello' when called from Dockerfile

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile

I am trying to read the module `hello.py` from Dockerfile and seeing the below error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'
```

I have tried changing the directory to the current working directory where `hello.py` is present, but that still doesn't help.

The tree structure as below with hello.py and Dockerfile at the same location:

```
           ├── Dockerfile
           ├── hello.py
           ├── __init__.py
           ├── Procfile
           ├── README.txt
           ├── requirements.txt
```

Dockerfile content:

```
FROM python:3.6.7

RUN pip install gunicorn

EXPOSE 5000

CMD PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/.. gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 hello:app
```

Output when running the container

```
-----> docker run -p 5000:5000 <image_name>

[2019-06-29 05:03:02 +0000] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-06-29 05:03:02 +0000] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (7)
[2019-06-29 05:03:02 +0000] [7] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-06-29 05:03:02 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
[2019-06-29 05:03:02 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hello'

[2019-06-29 05:03:02 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
[2019-06-29 05:03:02 +0000] [7] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-06-29 05:03:02 +0000] [7] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

What am i missing the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `COPY` line:

```
FROM python:3.6.7

RUN pip install gunicorn

COPY . . #copy everything in the context to the current dir in the container

EXPOSE 5000

CMD PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/.. gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 hello:app
```

otherwise the container would not include your files

Comment: Added the COPY command and built the image. Now after i try running the image  i see a different error:
[2019-07-06 02:22:33 +0000] [8] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-07-06 02:22:33 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
File "/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Comment: @sagarmehta you have to install flask -  so change `RUN pip install gunicorn` to `RUN pip install gunicorn flask`